# Create my own "URL Manager"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a http API, and I need a bit more flexibility than I'm used to in asp.net. It's pretty simple problem I have, and just need some help getting on the right track.

My problem is, that I want to create a response object based on the request. F.x a user can get a xml document when requesting: "myapi/images/5/xml". Or get it as a json if it had ended with json. I have no problems creating the right response objects. I just need a way to collect all the request in some object, then parse the URL with a regex and create the right response on that.

But how do I collect all requests on a web application?

Comment: Just curious what are you having the need to specify the return type in the URL. I think that is not a good design. You should have the client specify what type of return type they want through the `Accept` header in your request. The API will then read the request header for the accept type and then return appropriately.

Comment: [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) ???

Comment: And finally to your question. What do you mean "collect all the request in some object"? If you mean all the request header, when you do a http request operation, don't you make a request header? The http request header is used for that purpose, to hold all request information for the data they need.

Comment: Maybe you wanna check MVC pattern for .net. You can be very flexible with the URL's and deal with REGEX. Also supports json format.

You can start learning here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Sorry for the long dealy! I used the webapi: http://www.asp.net/web-api, can be used with either forms or mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably *don't* want to parse the whole URL with a regex. It'd probably be easier to hook into ASP.NET's routing engine:-

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "MyApi",
  routeTemplate: "myapi/{controller}/{id}/{responseType}",
  defaults: new
  {
    id = RouteParameter.Optional, responseType = RouteParameter.Optional
  });
```

Then your action method can accept a parameter `responseType` from the url.

I agree with steven's comment above, though, you should probably get the response type from the request header rather than from the url.